# SQL Server: how to use the results from a SQL procedure as a parameter for another stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need your help with the following scenario:

I have created the below stored procedure that allows me bringing all the users from a specific network that are registered on a specific network node ----we are discussing about millions of records here

```
Create PROCEDURE TestX

    @netID INT,-----parameter for Network ID
    @sts INT,------parameter for user status ID (active =0 , inactive = 1)
    @rnode INT ----parameter for NetworkNodeID

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @DT INT;
    SET @DT= CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(year,-15 ,GETDATE()),112))

Select 
 UserID
,RegistrationDate
,DateID
,NetworkID
,Registration_NetID_Node
,Current_NetID_Node_Orientation
,UserStatusID
From table UserX
where 
    
    networkID = @netID
AND statusID = @stsID
AND Registration_NetID_Node = @Rnode
AND DateID >= @DT
```

The topic is to check whether any user found in the procedure above, manages to login on a different network node based on a specific table with all the logins from the last 15 years.

The content of the Login is the below:----we can have multiple logins for each user.

```
Select
 UserID
,LoginType
,LoginDate
,NET_ID
,Node_ID_From
,Node_ID_To
FROm LoginTableX
where 
    LoginType in (1,2,5)
AND Node_ID_From = 136
AND Node_ID_To in (137,137)
```

My question is: Is there any chance to use the userID from the result of the Stored Procedure UserX (after running it with specific parameters) in another StoredProcedure wirtten to trak specific Logins, as parameter?
I want to know, which user managed to logged in from network node 136 to 137 and 138 nodes at any point in time, in the last 15 years.

For example let's say I am executing UserX '84', 'o','136' ---is giving me 1 milion distinct UserIds.
I want to create another stored procedure for Logins that should use as parameter the @UserID equal with each value found in the results of TestX. (I want this to work like an inner join between UserX and Logins but with a better performance)

Basically like this:

```
execute procedure Logins /*(let's say with the logic of the logins table above)*/
@playerId = (select playerID from (exec UserX '84', 'o','136'))
```

Comment: Don't write stored procedures to run queries.  Use user-defined functions.  They can then be used in other queries.  Very convenient.

Comment: Can you help me draft a function like this please?

Comment: @zoldxk the output I want is to get all the players that managed to do the logins from node 136 to the other 2 nodes (138 and 137)

Comment: You tagged your question with different DBMS tags, MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server. Include only the one you are using.

Comment: Why use a procedure or UDF? This is pretty trivial logic that can be accomplished with a view (to handle your obscure usage of dates). And why do you select 15 years worth of rows? That alone seems highly suspicious as a truly useful query. And re: "all users" - nope, it is limited to 15 years of rows. Do NOT overstate what it does or make assumptions based on your current data.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your procedure with a simple table-valued function. You can then use it in-line as you would any other table or view, for example:

```
create function dbo.TestX(@netID int, @stsID int, @rnode int)
returns table
as
return
    select 
        UserID
        ,RegistrationDate
        ,DateID
        ,NetworkID
        ,Registration_NetID_Node
        ,Current_NetID_Node_Orientation
        ,UserStatusID
    from [Table]
    where 
        networkID = @netID
        and statusID = @stsID
        and Registration_NetID_Node = @rnode
        and DateID >= Convert(int,Convert(varchar(8),DateAdd(year,-15 ,GetDate()),112))

go
```

You can then use it anywhere such as `select * from dbo.TestX(1,0,137)` or using `apply` etc. The parameters can be hard-coded or passed as values from other columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table valued function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_TestX]
(
    @netID INT,-----parameter for Network ID
    @sts INT,------parameter for user status ID (active =0 , inactive = 1)
    @rnode INT ----parameter for NetworkNodeID
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT 
         UserID
        ,RegistrationDate
        ,DateID
        ,NetworkID
        ,Registration_NetID_Node
        ,Current_NetID_Node_Orientation
        ,UserStatusID
    FROM UserX
    WHERE networkID = @netID
    AND statusID = @stsID
    AND Registration_NetID_Node = @Rnode
    AND DateID >= CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(year,-15 ,GETDATE()),112))
)
```

and use it in a query like below.

```
WITH  LoginsCTE AS (
SELECT
 UserID
,LoginType
,LoginDate
,NET_ID
,Node_ID_From
,Node_ID_To
FROM LoginTableX
WHERE 
    LoginType in (1,2,5)
AND Node_ID_From = 136
AND Node_ID_To in (137,137)
)
SELECT * FROM LoginsCTE LCTE
JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[udf_TestX](84, 0,136)
) DT
ON DT.UserID = LCTE.UserID
```